# insert table values into textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scripts

```
    function GetAllRows(chk,col1,col2) {
        $('#PrivilegeDisplaytabale').find('tr').each(function () {
          var row = $(this);
          var hh = "";
          if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
            hh += ($(this).find("td").eq(col1).html() + " ###  " + $(this).find("td").eq(col2).html());
           }
          $('.getPrivileges').val(hh);
       });
     }
```

My question is, why is my `.getPrivileges` class not getting populated? Meanwhile the hh variable is getting populated and `.getPrivileges` class is a textbox.

Comment: `$('#PrivilegeDisplaytabale tr').each(function () {`

Comment: `$('#PrivilegeDisplaytabale tr input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {`

Comment: could you please show us what `.getPrivileges` actually refers to in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is purely depends on what html element identified by getPrivileges class for example if its a paragraph tag as below

```
 <p class='getPrivileges'>
```

and if you try to do `$('.getPrivileges').val(value);`  it won't work; instead you should use `$('.getPrivileges').text(value);`